# What need install on TFS server

Tags: c#, tfs

I write library on c# (vs2010), which work with MS Office. In local computer it's successfully build. But when I try build on my local tfs server, I see exception:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets (176):
>     The "FindRibbons" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.BuildTasks, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, 
>     that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

If I understand correct, the library need placed in GAC (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL) on TFS Server. So. What I need install, that fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting up the build server for VSTO is a bit involved. The detailed modifications are described at a whitepaper referenced by the blog post, [How to Build Visual Studio 2010 Office Development Projects with TFS Team Build 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/ff624126.aspx). You need to package and deploy a few components and make a few environment changes.

Fortunately, the VSTO team provides a set of scripts that automate the packaging and deployment of the required components. The process is described at [Using Team Build with VSTO – Made Easier!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/04/13/using-team-build-with-vsto-made-easier-tobi-kral-aaron-cathcart.aspx)

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, the script was retired a long time ago and neither the blog post nor the [relevant MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff624126.aspx) were updated.